# ViewPager cannot keep on scrolling when a touch is placed out of its bounds

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have small area of screen where I put ViewPager. While I scroll ViewPager from inside of its area it works fine. But when my finger move beyond the bounds then scrolling is intercepted. This occurs on Android version lower then 4.2. On Android 4.2 scrolling keep on even if the touch was outside the bounds of ViewPager.

How can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could override the touch event of the ViewPager, and on an ACTION_DOWN event, call `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)`, then set it back to false on ACTION_UP.

This should keep other views from being able to intercept the touch events after you've started a touch event on the ViewPager.